# Dotfuscator for WinPhone 7 and XNA

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, dotfuscator

Does anyone know if Dotfuscator supports WinPhone7 and XNA applications ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently Dotfuscator does support full XNA applications, both obfuscation and injecting Runtime Intelligence analytics functionality.

Dotfuscator will fully support Windows Phone 7 applications, both Silverlight and XNA.  We have been working on it for a while and are currently putting the final touches on a beta that will be released soon.  You will also experience a high level of protection of your Silverlight win phone applications due to Dotfuscator's ability to analyze and obfuscate your XAML markup.

Watch our [blog](http://preemptive.com/blog/) for details of when we are ready to open up the beta.  Also, Dotfuscator will not only obfuscate Windows Phone 7 applications but if you subscribe to Runtime Intelligence you will be able to easily track how people are using your apps.